# How can I use ELSE IF inside GROUP_CONCAT?

Tags: mysql, if-statement, group-concat

I have an IF statement inside a mySQL query and it is working well:

```
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("animal:",if(animal.name="monkey","fred",""),",color: ",animal.color) SEPARATOR " <br>") AS animals
```

I want now add an ELSEIF:

```
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("animal:",if(animal.name="monkey","fred","")elseif(animal.name="cat","jane",""),",color: ",animal.color) SEPARATOR " <br>") AS animals
```

But I get an ERROR message:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if for details and examples.

Comment: @P.Salmon There is no example for group_concat

Comment: First clean up your if statement,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "if elseif endif" is a control statement whereas the if() is a function in MySQL. While they share the same name they are different things.

If you have multiple options, you can use CASE instead of IF.

```
SELECT 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT("animal:",
      CASE animal.name
        WHEN "monkey" THEN "fred"
        WHEN "cat" THEN "jane"
        ELSE "other"
      END,
      ",color: ",animal.color) SEPARATOR " <br>"
    ) AS animals
FROM (
  SELECT 'monkey' AS 'name', 'brown' AS 'color'
  UNION
  SELECT 'cat', 'white'
  UNION
  SELECT 'dog', 'black'
  ) AS animal
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested: CASE animal.name WHEN "monkey" THEN "fred" END CASE. But I get an ERROR: `Syntax error or access violation: 106` Can you show, how you mean it?

Comment: Finally found the solution. It is nessecary to write END in the end.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add a `if` in the `else` part of your `if`

```
group_concat(distinct concat("animal:",if(animal.name="monkey","fred",if(animal.name="cat","jane","")),",color: ",animal.color) separator " <br>") as animals
```

the `case` syntax is almost the same

```
group_concat(distinct concat("animal:",case animal.name when "monkey" then "fred" when "cat" then "jane" case "dog" then "donald" else "",",color: ",animal.color) separator " <br>") as animals
```

Comment: But I have actually around 5 ELSE IF. So how would I do that with more then one?

Comment: use the `case` operator, it's almost the same

Comment: Why do you use for MONKEY and CAT `when` and for DOG `case`?

Comment: Still getting ` Syntax error or access violation: 1064`

Comment: Finally found the solution. It is nessecary to write END in the end.